# Bug with switch in foreach

Tags: php, foreach, switch-statement

Here is code I have problem with - simple foreach iterating array. Sometimes element from array can has key "mailto" - in such case it should do some task. But for some reason first element with "0" key enters "mailto" case too.

```
<?php
    foreach (
        array(
            " this shouldnt appear, it's without mailto as key - 1",
            " this shouldnt appear, it's without mailto as key - 2",
            "mailto" => " this should appear ",
            " this shouldnt appear, it's without mailto as key - 3",
        ) as $type => $text
    ) {
        echo "#$type#\n";
        switch ($type) {
            case "mailto":
                echo ">$type< $text\n";

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
#0#
>0<  this shouldnt appear, it's without mailto as key - 1
#1#
#mailto#
>mailto<  this should appear 
#2#
```

Why first element appears?

Comment: You may need to escape `,` (comma) which is specified within every value, as this is conflicting with value seperator inside array. you can use forward slash for escaping

Comment: Even with letter-only text bug still occurs.

Comment: This is one of the cases where I think the PHP authors really should have created distinct array types, index-based and associative, like in Python and Ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the other answers pointed out: `switch` compares by value, it doesn't do type & value comparing. The fact that a string constant == 0 evaluates to true is just one of those PHP oddities/quirks, I guess. That said: You could either use *"real"*, hard coded keys, or you could use a cast:

```
foreach($theArray as $type => $text)
{
    echo "#$type#\n";
    switch ((string) $type)
    {//cast key to string
        case "mailto":
            echo ">$type< $text\n";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Job done.
That said, you really needn't concatenate strings you echo. In fact, [it's better not to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596098/php-closing-tag-deletes-the-line-feed/20596645#20596645). I'd just echo the values as comma-separated constants + variables:

```
echo '#', $type, '#', PHP_EOL;// use X-platform constant
switch ((string) $type)
{
    case 'mailto':
        echo '>', $type, '< ', $text, PHP_EOL;
        break;
}
```

will be *marginally* faster

Comment: I found your solution the most convenient for my needs, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your switch statement is doing a `==` comparison which means that php is typecasting the string `mailto` to a integer which equals 0.  So the case statement evaluates as true.

Since you are only using one value, change it to an if statement and use the strict comparison `===`

Comment: Well I'm using only one value for sake of simplicity in this example, but in real script there are other types. Converting to if-statement is only solution?

Answer (score 1):

The `switch/case` construct is implemented using the `==` equal operator.

Now if you try this:

```
>> "mailto" == 0
true
>> "mailto" == 1
false
>>
```

You can see how PHP makes it wrong.
"mailto" is cast into an integer value of 0 for the equality test.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears to be easily fixed by adding another case to your switch statement, like so:

```
switch ($type) 
{
    case 0:
        break;
    case 'mailto':
        echo ">$type< $text\n";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I suspect the issue with 0 being compared to 'mailto' coming up as true has to do with PHP's loose type comparison. When you compare an integer with a  string in PHP with only two equals (==) it returns true.

Another fix to force the comparison to be done as a string and therefore avoid having to add this additional case is to cast the $type to a string, like so:

```
switch ((string) $type) 
{
    case 'mailto':
        echo ">$type< $text\n";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the non-type comparison of `==` in `switch()` causes `0=="mailto"` to be true.

If you need to add other case statements and want to keep the original structure, you can force the first key to be a 1, and avoid the issue.

```
foreach (
    array(
        1=>" this shouldnt appear, it's without mailto as key - 1", 
        " this shouldnt appear, it's without mailto as key - 2",
        "mailto" => " this should appear ",
        " this shouldnt appear, it's without mailto as key - 3",
    ) as $type => $text
) {
```

Otherwise, just switch to a simple if using strict comparison `===`

```
foreach (
    array(
        " this shouldnt appear, it's without mailto as key - 1",
        " this shouldnt appear, it's without mailto as key - 2",
        "mailto" => " this should appear ",
        " this shouldnt appear, it's without mailto as key - 3",
    ) as $type => $text
) {
    echo "#$type#\n";
    if($type === 'mailto'){
            echo ">$type< $text\n";
    }
}
```