# Concatenation-assignment in PHP

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and I just read about Assignment Operators and I saw this 
`$a .= 5`   which means $a equals $a concatenated with 5. To test this I coded a simple script

```
    <?php
        $a = 12345;
        $a .=6;

        $b = 12345;
        $b .=006;

        $c = 12345;
        $c .=678;
        echo " a=$a and b=$b c=$c" ;

    ?>
```

the output was `a=123456 and b=123456 c=12345678`.My question is why the b isn't equal with 12345006? Is it because treats 6 == 006?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because numbers with leading zeroes are treated as octals. if the concatenation would've included the leading zeroes, then `006` would've been interpretted as a string, which makes no sense, because it hasn't got quotes around it.
If you want `006` to be treated as a string, write it as one: `'006'`. Leave it as is, and it'll be interpreted as an octal:

```
$b = $a = 123;
$a .= 8;
$b .= 010;//octal
echo $a, ' === ', $b, '!';//echoes 1238 === 1238!
```

Just as an asside: yes, those are comma's/. `echo` is a language construct to which you can push multiple values, separated by comma's. The upshot of using comma's is that the values aren't concatenated into a single string before being pushed to the output stream.
This means that it is (marginally faster). The downsides: there aren't any AFAIK.

In case you're interested in the internals of PHP, [I've explain this a bit more detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596098/php-closing-tag-deletes-the-line-feed/20596645#20596645)...

Comment: @Nat95: Thanks, in case you are interested, I've added some more details on this topic, and some details about the PHP internals

Comment: +1 for a well-detailed and well-explained answer. Plus, I was looking for that term yesterday about the leading `0` being treated as an octal. I'm going to have to remember that one from hereoin, my short-term memory is completely shot!

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I take it you ment to say _"hereon"_, because that _"i"_ + the statement _"My short-time memory is shot"_ is suggesting some severe substance abuse :-P

Comment: I guess I did mean `hereon`. I've always had short-term memory problems, a learning disability plus a slight case of dyslexia.

Comment: Oh, and I've been a "good boy" for well over 20 years ;-) It's just coffee and cigarettes now. lol

Comment: Ok, I see the typo I made lol - I meant "hereonin" --- that almost looks like "heroine" hahaha!

Answer (score 5):

Because 006 is treated as the octal number 6, which is the converted to the string "6", and concatenated to "12345" (which is the number 12345 converted to a string). 
Use $b .= "006", and the result will be 12345006.

Comment: then the output would be a string?

Comment: Yes, the result of the . or .= operator is always a string.

Comment: @Nat95, You can `cast` to integer like this.. `$b = (int)$b;`

Answer (score 0):

Just try b as a string:

```
$b.= '006';
```

Then you will get output 12345006.